# camera intent onActivityResult causes application object and activity to re create

Tags: android, android-camera

The below code is working fine in some devices. but in samsung galaxy y duos and some other devices ,on taking picture and click on save,  application object oncreate and activity onCreate are called again.this causes lose of  data stored in application object.how to avoid it

Application  code as below :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "####MyApplication on Craetet called");
    }


}
```

My Activity code as Below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    MyApplication app;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
        Log.i(TAG, "#### MainActivity  onCreate called with values " + app.a + " " + app.b + " " + app.c);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        tv1.setText("" + app.a);
        tv2.setText("" + app.b);
        tv3.setText("" + app.c);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                app.a = 5;
                app.b = 6;
                app.c = 8;

                Log.i(TAG, "after onclick  values " + app.a + " " +  app.b + " "+ app.c);

                Intent intentPicture = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intentPicture, SELECT_CAMERA);

            }
        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_CAMERA) {

                Log.i(TAG, "after image selected values " + app.a + " " + app.b
                    + " " + app.c);

                tv1.setText("" + app.a);
                tv2.setText("" + app.b);
                tv3.setText("" + app.c);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

my logs are

```
04-09 23:58:44.888: I/MyApplication(15189): ####MyApplication on Craetet called
04-09 23:58:45.160: I/MainActivity(15189): #### MainActivity  onCreate called with values 0 0 0
04-10 00:02:30.115: I/MainActivity(15795): after onclick  values 5 6 8


04-10 00:02:37.550: I/MyApplication(16016): ####MyApplication on Craetet called
04-10 00:02:37.587: I/MainActivity(16016):#### MainActivity  onCreate called with values 0 0 0
04-10 00:02:37.592: I/MainActivity(16016): after image selected values 0 0 0
```

Comment: is your orientation fixed for this activity??? in Manifest???

Comment: coz there is a big chance  oncreate will get called if config changes is ON in your manifest

Comment: orientation is not fixed

Comment: yeah than in many phones when you switch to Default camera from app the orientation changes

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I am habing a similar problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your activity manifest try  using this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

and override onConfigurationChanged in your activity
 and try again..it should not go yo ONCreate

Comment: above solution is not working. my activity's onConfigurationChanged never called but onConfigurationChanged of application object is called.this is not happend in samsung tab.this only happens celkon a95 an galaxy y duos both are dual sim mobiles and rams are below 256mb

Comment: It also doesn't take effect on Galaxy SIII. Works on other devices, so the reason is Samsung's custom camera implementation. Still searching for a solution...

Comment: well many more things are not working on the current devices..m screwedd